# What is T_e in stepper motor equation?

Tags: stepper-motor, equation

The description for T_e is missing on this page.

Source: https://se.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/steppermotor.html

Comment: Motor-developed torque. (= acceleration torque + viscous friction torque)

Comment: If you consider the last term of the summation ( \$T_d \cdot \sin (4N_r \theta)\$ ) you can figure out it is a torque, because \$T_d\$ is a torque and a sine is dimensionless.